# var_dump filter_var FILTER_SANITIZE_URL return behaviour

Tags: php, var-dump, filter-var

here I am baffled as to why `FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` in `var_dump` returns a wrong string length and doesnt remove the tags such as . this happenes in all filter_var Predefined Filter Constants. is this a bug or there is a logic behind it?

I am using PHP 5.4 because I have to, our servers run on it. let me demonstarte.
I have this URL:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string';
```

if I sanitise it and var_dump it:

```
var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

it will return:

```
string(60) "http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string"
```

NOW if I put malicious code in URL

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = "<?php echo $var; ?>";
    alert(x);

}
</script>a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string';
```

same code: `var_dump(filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));`
will return this:

```
string(132) "http://www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string"
```

Pay attention to the type and length of returned var. 72 characters more than the previous but clearly the string is still 60 characters long. why does var_dump or filter_var behave in such manners please? if it is a bug has this been fixed. as I record these type of data I need this function to return exact number of characters.

Comment: FILTER_SANITIZE_URL removed all unnecessary characters from the url, including spaces, if u check view source it shows <script>functionmyFunction(){varx="<?phpecho$var;?>";alert(x);}</script>

Comment: @devpro ... I know ... but why does it still return 132 characters on var_dump?

Comment: because, <script>functionmyFunction(){varx="<?phpecho$var;?>";alert(x);}</script> included in this count, and y not visible, because its inside the <script> tag... and your browser will not show it.

Comment: if you look at var_dump manual it will say that it will return the type and the length of string but the length is wrong!

Comment: i hope answer will explain each and everything.

Comment: `var_dump(htmlspecialchars(filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)));` will tell you the truth. (Or a look at the HTML source code, _before_ it is interpreted as HTML by the browser.)

Comment: @CBroe: yes u r right, plz chk in view source..

Comment: OK Now I understand! the answer to question should have been because it only removes the unfriendly urlcharacters and doesnt actually SANITIZE the URL of tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL` removed all unnecessary characters from the URL, including spaces, if you check view source it shows

```
<script>functionmyFunction(){varx="<?phpecho$var;?>";alert(x);}</script>
```

**Why return 132 characters?**

Because `<script>` tag and inner code also included as a string. FILTER_SANITIZE_URL does not remove tags it just removes spaces and This filter allows all letters, digits and

```
$-_.+!*'(),{}|\\^~[]`"><#%;/?:@&=
```

to remove malicious code use other functions such as `strip_tags()`.

```
$var = filter_var(strip_tags($url), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

**If code included as string then why not display?**

Because you are using var_dump and checking result on browser, and you can not view any code inside `<script>` tag on browser until unless go to page view source.

**If you remove `<script>` tag, what should be happened?**

If you removed `<script>` tag, than it will show following:

```
string(115) "http://www.example.com/index.php?functionmyFunction(){varx="";alert(x);}a=1&b=2&c=3&d=some%20string"
```

17 characters of `<script></script>` should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not explain my question. I know everything on what you have written but still the correct behaviour should be string(60) as it returns 60 characters... var_dump should return the number of final charcaters and not the ones which was removed by filter_var before hand.

Comment: which characters removed by filter_var ??? do u know??? @DanielPurPur, it didnt removed <script>... just removed spaces.. and u can not view on browser, remove <script> tag and check result.

Comment: I already have done that. I have done a lot of tests before posting a question. why the removed characters are still counted in var_dump. it seems we have a misunderstanding here. my question is completely on a different subject.

Comment: @DanielPurPur: i think issue is that, u r thinking, <script> and inside the script code is removed.. but its not. visible in view source. inside the script tag

Comment: OK Now I understand! the answer to question should have been because it only removes the unfriendly urlcharacters and doesnt actually SANITIZE the URL of tags. Thanks